# Problems deploying a SSAS cube in Azure

Tags: azure, ssas, sql-server-2014

I am having problems deploying a ssas cube in Azure. I have designed a cube in SSDT.
The structure of the cube is correct and I can access to the database placed in azure machine
from my local laptop.My SSDT project is created in my local laptop. I have tried ti deploy to azure machine and
 get the following error;

"The project could not be deployed to the 'mbitsql.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com' server because of the following connectivity problems :

> A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running.To
>   verify or update the name of the target server, right-click  on the
>   project in Solution Explorer, select Project Properties, click on the
>   Deployment tab, and then enter the name of the server."

These are my tests or checks:

- The cube is correct generated, the error is in deployment
- I can access to Azure sql server database succesfuly, the problem is with the analysis services.
- I have checked the server name in the implementation propierties, I have tested with DNS name
  and with IP.
- I have checked to access Analysis services from the ssms of Azure and I can access. I have
  checked that analysis services and sql browser services are running (both local account)
- I have created security input rules ion azure to allow access to 2382 port

I don't know where is the problem.... I use SQL Server 2016 y SSDT 2015

There is something, that I don't understand, I have given an user/pass in the datasource to access
to sql server azure database, but in the project there isn't a place to put the user/pass for SSAS.

I don't understand this, because if you log from SSMS you always put a user/pass for both (sql server database and ssas)

Answer (score 1):

Did you open 2382 or 2383? 2383 is correct unless you customized the SSAS port.

Is the Azure VM domain joined? If you are logged into your laptop as MYDOMAIN\juan do you use that same user to Remote Desktop to the VM? If not close and open SSDT with:
 `runas /netonly /user:mbitsql\vmUserName "c:\pathTo\devenv.exe"` so that SSDT can authenticate with the VM when you deploy.

Comment: Thanks Greg,I have opened both: 2383 and 2382. I am logged in my laptop with my local user, but when I log into the Azure VM using Remote Desktop I use another user (the user of the VM). I don't know how to change user when I do the deployment it doesn't ask me for user. I have looked the place to insert user/pass of the azure VM in SDT but I didn'st find. How can I do it? .

Comment: @juanvg1972 close SSDT and relaunch it with the runas command I mentioned

Comment: @juanvg1972 also check both that the Azure portal has 2383 open and that the local VM firewall has that port open

Comment: Thanks it worked relaunching with runsu.   Thanks Greg

Comment: @juanvg1972 if I have answered your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark.