# Can't connect to remote Azure SQL Analysis Services instance from SSDT

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssas

As title says, I'm trying to connect from SQL Server Data Tools 2012 to an instance of Analysis Services (SQL Server 2012 Standard) on an Azure Machine with Windows Server 2012. I can connect and get the data origin but when I try to elaborate a dimension or deploy a cube I get the error (translated):

> Can't connect. Check that server is running

Note that from inside the machine I can do it properly.

Things I did:

- Opened ports 1433 (SQL Server), 2382 (SQL Server Browser), 2383 (Analysis Services)
- Created TCP inbound rules on the Azure Machine on ports 1433, 2382, 2383

Thank you.

Comment: Is it the default instance? Is the Azure VM domain joined to the same domain your laptop is on? Is the VM visible over site-to-site VPN so it looks like the server is on your local network or can you only connect via the public IP address over the open internet?

Comment: If it is not domain joined then see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40449368/5070440

Comment: It worked, thank you very much!